# Can I bundle a local .whl file dependency inside a python wheel distribution file?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, software-distribution, python-wheel

I want to bundle a local distribution .whl file inside another wheel file as a dependency.

dist_pkg1.whl (referenced wheel file,is a local file)

dist_pkg2.whl is dependent on dist_pkg1.whl, and I need to embed dist_pkg1.whl inside dist_pkg2.whl, so that, whenever I install dist_pkg1.whl, dist_pkg2.whl should be installed as a dependency.
Is there any way I can acheve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `pyproject.toml`:

```
dependencies = [
    "dist_pkg2 @ file:///path/to/dist_pkg2.whl"
]
```

You might also use `requirements.txt` file, although it is not used during packaging process. Still it might help to resolve your problem:

```
./path/to/dist_pkg2.whl
```